# Perform vector operations on numpy arrays stored within dictionaries?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

[image]I have a dictionary that stores the name of the river where the data was collected in the key, and values are a numpy array of all of the chemical data collected from that river.  I would like to go in and perform vector operations on those arrays to split them up by site within the river, where each site would then get its own array that I can run stats on.  How can I go about doing this?

Attached is an excerpt from the top of one of the input spreadsheets.  They will all have those same 14 columns, but the rows will vary from a couple hundred to a couple thousand.  I will have several dozen of these spreadsheets. The spreadsheets are already stored in a dictionary described above, but if you have a better way to store them I am open to suggestions.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

os.chdir("pathGoesHere")
path=os.getcwd()        

riverDict={}
for sheet in os.listdir(path):
    if sheet.endswith('.csv'):
        name=sheet[0:-4]
        dataIn=pd.read_csv(sheet)
        dataIn=np.array(dataIn.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'))
        riverDict[name]=dataIn

#I need a way to go into each array stored within this dictionary and slice it
#up to do stats on the arrays individually, as well as comparative stats 
#across subsets of the arrays.
```

Comment: If you have only such spreadsheet-like, regular data, have a look at `pandas` if you haven't stumbled across it yet. The dictionaries can easily be converted to `pandas` `dataframes`.

Comment: I used some pandas tools to read the spreadsheets into python, but I am not sure how to handle dataframes as I am new to using python.  I will look into those, thanks.

Comment: One more note - although I think `pandas` offers a lot of convenience especially for spreadsheet-like data analysis: if it comes to basic number crunching, I prefer to work in plain `numpy` for performance reasons and flexibility. So just keep an open mind for other options ;-)

Comment: The spreadsheet display doesn't help us much.  We need to see the python structure(s). - dataframe, dictionary, arrays.  `vectorize` normally refers to actions within one array, not actions across elements of a dictionary.

Comment: You mention 'sites' but I don't see anything about how they are identified.

Comment: Column A, "site name" is the site identifier.  I cannot append all the rivers into the same array for processing, as site numbers were re-used across rivers and are therefore not unique.

Comment: It should be easy to load one file into pandas dataframe.  Figure out what you want to with that frame.  Only then should worry about multiple frames.